# new Thread() and Garbage Collection Memory Leak?

Tags: c#, multithreading, garbage-collection

I have the following code:

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
{
    // something short
})).Start();
```

Can garbage collector finalize this instance of `Thread` while it is in the `Stopped` state?

Lifetime of this thread is:

1. `Before Started`
2. `Running`
3. `Stopped`

When this `Thread` will end of their work this will be collected by *Garbage Collector* or they will keep handle to that thread for maybe restart them in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Thread` instance are not referenced by the system after the thread terminates.

It is not possible to restart a stopped `Thread` instance.

Comment: No that means can't finalize that?

Comment: How to finalize that? Even if i have handle to that.

Comment: The GC will do that automatically after you don't have any more references to it.  It is impossible explicitly free an object.  .Net objects don't have handles.

Comment: But look at code, i dont have references to that `Thread` at all, then when this thread will be stopped (end of work) then will be finalized?

Comment: ".Net objects don't have handles." is that technically true? I though any .NET object has got a handle and lots of other metadata pointers. They are just not exposed to the user code. CLR, however, use handles and references to do many things including GC, JIT, method resolving etc.

Comment: @oleksii: You're right; I should have said `expose`.  (in spite of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtimemethodhandle.aspx)

Comment: The other day I was poking shared CLR code, discovered so much new stuff and internal details. If anyone interested here is a link to [CLR v.2 shared code](https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4917)

Comment: @oleksii: See also http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx  for managed-only .Net 4 source.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Once:

1. The thread is stopped (e.g. the delegate called has returned).
2. There isn't a rooted reference to the `Thread` object any more.

Then it can be collected. You won't notice though, because at this point you have no reference to the object to examine it through, there's no code running on the thread it represents, and there never will be.

I suppose you could have a `WeakReference` that held a reference to the object, and when its `IsAlive` was false you'd know it had been collected. Why would you care though?

Comment: i have huge memory leak ;-( thats why and i have problems to solve that

Comment: @Svisstack try memory profilers or SOS debugger to see what sits in you memory.

Comment: Yes, what @oleksii said. If you've a problem with your memory, look at your memory, not your threads ;)